# I have to insert nested document batch field into parent document when user select "_id" using mongodb driver manager

Tags: php, mongodb

following is medicinename collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e25cc9c1e48000083005337"),
    "medicine_name" : "nicip",
    "potencyy" : "2mg",
    "login_id" : ObjectId("5e2166cc58c10dfdfd90e4c5"),
    "medicine_type" : {
        "medicine_type_id" : ObjectId("5e21e0a71c7f00009b001206"),
        "medicine_type_nm" : "tablet"
    },
    "unit" : {
        "unit_id" : ObjectId("5e25cc871e48000083005336"),
        "unit_name" : "qty qty"
    }
}
```

following is expected output....

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e25cc9c1e48000083005337"),
    "medicine_name" : "nicip",
    "potencyy" : "2mg",
    "login_id" : ObjectId("5e2166cc58c10dfdfd90e4c5"),
    "medicine_type" : {
        "medicine_type_id" : ObjectId("5e21e0a71c7f00009b001206"),
        "medicine_type_nm" : "tablet"
    },
    "unit" : {
        "unit_id" : ObjectId("5e25cc871e48000083005336"),
        "unit_name" : "qty qty"
    }
   "batch" : {
        "batch_id" : ObjectId("5e25cc871e48000083006337"),
        "batch_no" : "abc123",
        "mrp" : "600"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for the future endeavor at Stack overflow. Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: What is the concern here, its not clear. I guess you are looking for [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)

Comment: yes i am lokking for $set but i dont know how to use $set in mongodb/driver/manager..................thnk u